# How to save changes in bulk edited files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, frontend, editor, backend, liquid

I have to replace a modifier `| within: collection` in 43 lines of 11 liquid files. This is a Shopify ecommerce site. As soon as I saw `43 results in 11 files - Open in editor`, I clicked it so a new page opened with only the snippets from all 11 files. When attempting to save after replacing the modifiers in this new page, I expected it to save the changes to all files resulting in them reflecting as modified files in the Source tree version control. But presseing CTR+S brings a explorer window to save this a new file. How can I save these changes to the respective files so that they just appear modified in the version control? Attached is the image of the VS code page showing what I did.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that all occurrences are to be replaced, you can click the Replace All button as in the red circle of the attached image.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgBwY.png)

Comment: It worked, thanks. I didn't have to even click save.